# Jquery fire function when another function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

Is there a way to fire a function when another function has completed in a manner that is similar to DOM events?

e.g. (I know it's not possible but...)

```
$('body').on('myFunction', function(){
    alert('My function was called.');
})
```

Comment: I don't see your full code, but why not call the 2nd function at the end of the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is absolute no way to do that unless you can replace the function (i.e. have access to its scope).

If you do have access to the scope it becomes very easy though and does not need any jQuery at all:

```
var origFunc = theFunction;
theFunction = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // run before the call
    var rv = origFunc.apply(this, args);
    // run after the call
    return rv;
};
```

See MDN for information about the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) containing the arguments passed to the function. Using `slice` to convert it to a plain array is unfortunately necessary since browsers such as IE9 fail to follow the ES5 standard properly which requires `apply` to accept any array-like object.

Comment: Thanks! It does have global scope and your example works perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is completely what you want. But I think you should give a try to jquery `Deferred` objects. Have a look at the jquery documentation here - [Jquery Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

A brief overview -

- You can specify callbacks for done/fail/always events of a deferred object.
- All you now need to do is call the resolve/reject events on this deferred object.
- Triggering this event will run the method specified in corresponding call back.

I have compiled this little fiddle as a demo. - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XB87p/).

Hope this helps.